# Shading for my hands geometry is different to rest of model

Tags: modeling

[image]

Also when i export my fbx and import is into unreal the hands are like semi see through and transparent.

Thanks In Advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay the normals for my geometry were flipped, you can flip them again by selecting all the faces, then press W, then select Flip Normals.